# PHP ADOdB SQL query times out

Tags: php, timeout, adodb

Using ADOdb to access MS SQL Server in a database intensive PHP application. A few queries and stored procedures run longer than 30 seconds and ADODB throws an exception for a query timeout. There is no ADOdb setting to adjust the timeout.  Setting a longer command timeout in SQL Server does not work as it is apparently timing out in the ADOdb driver.

How can I extend the command timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I've actually run into this issue before.  The error I was getting was:

```
Fatal error: ado_mssql error: [0: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Query timeout expired].
```

If that's the error that you're getting, then I may be able to help.
The first answer would be to look at your actual query and see if you can optimize it.  Assuming that's already been done, you should open up ***adodb/adodb-ado5.inc.php*** or ***adodb/adodb-ado.inc.php*** depending on what version of PHP you're using.

In that file, look for `function _connect`.  You'll want to change it from this:

```
function _connect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword,$argDBorProvider, $argProvider= ''){
    ...
    ...
    if ($argDatabasename) $argHostname .= ";DATABASE=$argDatabasename"; 
    if ($argUsername) $argHostname .= ";$u=$argUsername";
    if ($argPassword)$argHostname .= ";$p=$argPassword";
    if ($this->debug) ADOConnection::outp( "Host=".$argHostname." \n version=$dbc->version");
    @$dbc->Open((string) $argHostname);
    $this->_connectionID = $dbc;

    $dbc->CursorLocation = $this->_cursor_location;
    return  $dbc->State > 0;
    } catch (exception $e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

to this:

```
function _connect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword,$argDBorProvider, $argProvider= ''){
    ...
    ...
    if ($argDatabasename) $argHostname .= ";DATABASE=$argDatabasename"; 
    if ($argUsername) $argHostname .= ";$u=$argUsername";
    if ($argPassword)$argHostname .= ";$p=$argPassword";
    if ($this->debug) ADOConnection::outp( "Host=".$argHostname."
\n version=$dbc->version");
    @$dbc->Open((string) $argHostname);

    $dbc->CommandTimeout = 120;

    $this->_connectionID = $dbc;

    $dbc->CursorLocation = $this->_cursor_location;
    return  $dbc->State > 0;
    } catch (exception $e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

The key part is

> **$dbc->CommandTimeout = 120;**

You can adjust your timeout as needed, but also be aware of other php.ini settings or other services that may be affected with a longer timeout.

Hope this helps, I've also written a slighty more in-depth write-up about this a while ago if you're curious: http://pointent.com/adodb_query_timeout_expired_fix.html